# Get the content of the first column

Tags: vimscript

I'm writing a vim function to comment the selected lines in visual mode. Then I have written the following function to toggle the "#" character. I want insert the # when thereisn't and remove it when it's there.

```
function Mycomment()
    if col(1.)=="^#"
        :s/^#//g
    else
        :s/^/#/g
    endif
endfunction
```

Obviously doesn't work. The biggest problem is to know what's the content of the column 1.

Comment: May have figured this out already but `col()` is not used to get content...it's used to get the column number/index (of the cursor, or a mark, or ...). And it takes a string or a two-element list.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I solved in this way:

```
function Commenta()
    let curline = getline(line('.'))
    let primo = strpart(curline, 0, 1)
    if primo=="#"
        :s/^#//g
    else
        :s/^/#/g
    endif
endfunction
```

Comment: You could simplify this by using the `=~` operator to check if the line begins with `#`, removing the need to save the current line and extract the first character into variables: `if getline(line('.')) =~ "^#"`.

Comment: Welcome to VI, I just upvoted your solution :)  Also for lots of comment functionality there are plugins available like https://github.com/preservim/nerdcommenter, https://github.com/tpope/vim-commentary, and https://github.com/tomtom/tcomment_vim.